# Restrict mouse movement over a specified window handle

Tags: windows, winapi, safari, mouse

I'm looking to simulate a kiosk mode for Safari on Windows.  OSX will not work with my input hardware and Chrome's GPU acceleration is too slow for the machine I'm using.

The only plausible solution [so far] is to run Safari and send an F11 (fullscreen) keystroke, but prevent the URL bar from expanding when the mouse reaches the top pixels of the screen.

I've looked and can't seem to find any good solution and would like to know if I can restrict the cursor movement from reaching the top pixel of the screen?

If anyone has any other solutions, that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`ClipCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx) function to do this.

> Confines the cursor to a rectangular area on the screen. If a subsequent cursor position (set by the **SetCursorPos** function or the mouse) lies outside the rectangle, the system automatically adjusts the position to keep the cursor inside the rectangular area.

Comment: After looking at the doc I wonder, does it work between applications or do you need to inject code to make it work for the browser?

Comment: @rasmus I suspect you are right that DLL injection is required

Comment: I'm almost angry I searched for so long and didn't run into this, you are awesome! (I was prepared to not even get a suitable answer)

Comment: Also, DLL injection was not required. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can poll the cursor position and correct it using a timer, but this is not ideal. You could also cover the top bar by a transparent topmost window. This way, input will never reach the top bar.

EDIT: If Internet explorer is an option you have the possibility to use the COM object to embed what you need in a custom application. Other browsers might have similar APIs, but I'm not familiar with them.