# How do I make a faster c#.NET timer alternative?

Tags: c#, timer, visual-studio-2015

I currently am using a timer for a script I wrote in Visual Studio 2015. I set the interval of the timer to 1 ms but it's not fast enough. The function of the timer is to keep the mouse in the center of the screen without allowing it to move away. Fast movements of the mouse will shortly pull the mouse away from the center, after which the timer will immediately recenter it. However, this isn't acceptable for my situation and I need it to be so fast that the cursor cannot move away from the center. Perhaps there is something better than a timer?

I am making this to avoid an issue regarding dual monitors which I decided to take upon myself to fix. (So this is a personal program)

Comment: Check this out. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b6aff81-feb4-4846-85d5-232b8159779f/how-to-make-the-timer-interval-less-than-1-ms-?forum=vblanguage

Comment: Why not restrict the mouse movement instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219151/restrict-mouse-movement-over-a-specified-window-handle

Comment: No, I'm creating this for myself as I need it for a game to avoid losing focus from it.

Comment: I also don't understand why I got downvoted...

Comment: @DarioMazhara likely downvoted due to you not attempting to solve it, and instead asking for people to do the work for you.

Comment: I actually did attempt to solve it. Using the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to restrict the movements of the cursor to some area you can use **Clip** property of the **System.Windows.Forms.Cursor** object.

This function allows you to define a clipping rectangle that restricts the movements of the cursor to those bounds.

You can find some information about this property in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip(v=vs.110).aspx) of MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Hope you not trying to create a virus. 

But have you tried using OnMouseMove event instead of a timer.

Comment: Hope you're not being serious about me creating a virus.

Comment: Well I'm sorry if it sounds offensive. its just that I cant see any area where you would need this except in an attempt to stop someone from using his mouse. Hope the onmousemove works for you though.